# working with externalinterface js

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, externalinterface

I am beginner with **ExternalInterface js** and truly i doesn't know about is that how to working with it.
I have 100 flash video all on web. user visit on web and started saw first video. When the first video end the pop up window opened and showing **play again** or **Next Video**.
When **Next Video** link clicked and URL of next video open and then next video will play. and so on...

i just need guidance from where to start and any help about understanding to externalInterface or any other way to do this task..

**i am not asking for code.. just need guidance . from where to start and what is right way to do this.**

Comment: Please take more time proofreading when you ask questions. More importantly, [*what have you tried?*](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: sir i am not asking for code.. just need guidance . from where to start.

Comment: Start by reading the API, and when you actually have a question that needs answering, ask a question. What you've posted isn't a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Actionscript to call a Javascript Function:

**The JS:**

```
function sayHello(data){
    alert("Hello, "+data.name);
}
```

**The AS:**

```
ExternalInterface.call("sayHello",{name:"John Doe"});
```

Or, you can do the reverse and use JS to call an AS function

**The AS:**

```
ExternalInterface.addCallback("sayHello",function(name:String){
    trace("Hello, "+name)
});
```

**The JS:**

```
myFlashMovie.sayHello("John Doe");
```